# Issue finding replacement for delete_marker? while upgrading aws-sdk gem to version 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I've been trying to upgrade from 'aws-sdk-v1' to 'aws-sdk' (the gem for version 2 of the aws sdk).
For version 1, this block of code works:

```
AWS::S3.new.buckets['bucket-name'].versions.each do |version|
  if version.delete_marker?
    version.delete
  end
end
```

For version 2 of the sdk, I can't find an equivalent to `delete_marker?`:

```
Aws::S3::Resource.new.bucket('bucket-name').object_versions.each do |version|
  if version.SOMETHING_ELSE
    version.delete
  end
end
```

Also note that for version 2, I switched `versions` to `object_versions` which I *think* is the right change for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going with `version.class == Aws::S3::Types::DeleteMarkerEntry` for lack of finding a better programmatic solution.

Answer (score 1):

I found this while digging through the gem within their [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)

> Feature - Aws::S3 - · You can now use the Expired object delete
>   markers expiration policy to automatically remove the current version
>   delete marker when previous versions of the object no longer exist.

So i doubt there is an alternative to `delete_marker?` in v2

See [HERE](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/intro-lifecycle-rules.html#intro-lifecycle-rules-actions) for more info.